# Populate a combobox from an array list populated from an SQL statment

Tags: eclipse, combobox, javafx

I am trying to populate a ComboBox with a list that is populated by a SQL statement.

I tried this:

```
public void buildData(){        
  ObservableList<ComboBox>  data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

  Connection conn = db.makeConnection();
    try{      
        String SQL = "Select Feature from FeaturesTable Order By Feature";            
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
        while(rs.next()){
            ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
            cb.featureCombo.set(rs.getString("Feature"));                       

            featureCombo.add(cb);                  
        }
        featureCombo.setItems(data);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error under cb.featureCombo.set of "featureCombo cannot be resolved or is not a field" but featureCombo exists as:

```
@FXML
private ObservableList<ComboBox> featureCombo;
```

and then another error under featureCombo.setItems(data); probably because of the same problem.

I'm not set on this method if someone has a better way to do this.

Comment: You are making a list of comboboxes....

Comment: Ok any suggestions to achieve what I'm hoping to achieve? @chancea

Comment: I am a java/js person, never used javafx before but hopefully my answer is still valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you desire a ComboBox named featureCombo, you are going to have to declare it as a ComboBox and not as `private ObservableList<ComboBox> featureCombo;` which is making an `ObservableList`

Something like

```
@FXML
ComboBox<String> featureCombo;
```

Then in your method, you need to make a list of `String` to populate the ComboBox (you currently have a list of ComboBox)

```
public void buildData(){        
  ObservableList<String>  data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); //List of String

  Connection conn = db.makeConnection();
    try{      
        String SQL = "Select Feature from FeaturesTable Order By Feature";            
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
        while(rs.next()){
            data.add(rs.getString("Feature")); //add the String to the list                                     
        }
        featureCombo.setItems(data); //Set the list of String as the data for your combo box
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anna I am happy I solved this particular issue for you but I do hope that I also bettered your understanding of how `Objects` work in OOP.  It is a necessary skill to have to better your programming skill.  Please take some time to understand my comments and such and don't just copy-paste without thinking, that won't help you in the future.

Comment: But you shouldn't use raw types: i.e. you should declare `ComboBox<String> featureCombo`. And according to the code posted in the question, you are `@FXML`-injecting this, so you shouldn't call `new ComboBox()`.

Comment: @James_D does that look better? I am only familiar with `Java` not `javafx`

Comment: Required tweaking but got me in the right direction.